# Missing ; before statement in superfish

Tags: javascript, jquery, superfish

I've a problem in my superfish plugin. My site works great on my pc and demo site but in original host I have error in supefish.js

firebug says "missing ; before statement"
and locates this string :

[Break On This Error]

```
...om:'auto'}).animate({height:0},150)})            $('.sf-menu li li').not('.current').hove...
```

I turned it to this but nothing changed :

```
...om:'auto'}).animate({height:0},150)})        ;       $('.sf-menu li li').not('.current').hove...
```

Comment: wonderful , it solved my problem. Tank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like a newline issue. I take it the superfish.js script was made on a Mac and your server is Linux? Just use your favourite text editor to convert the newlines to Windows format, which works with every kind of OS.